# Simple HTML DOM Parser - Content rendered by browser but not shown in source

Tags: php, ajax, json, parsing, dom

I am using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse product pages from JD.com, for example: http://item.jd.com/1023433.html

The problem I am facing is that the Web browser renders the price of the product but when I do a view source, the price, which I figured to be within the `<strong>` tag isn't shown.

```
<strong class="p-price"  id="jd-price"></strong>
```

When I render the page, I can't get the price either. Below is my code:

```
include_once ("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file("http://item.jd.com/1023433.html");
$price = $html->find("#jd-price",0);
echo $price->plaintext;
```

It is probably expected that the result is empty, since in the source code, there's nothing in between `<strong class="p-price"  id="jd-price"></strong>`, but when the page is rendered or when I do `echo $html->save()`, the price appears.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's probably using an ajax call to fetch some of the product data. The _view source_ option in browsers shows you the initial state of the DOM before any events or ajax requests which may have manipulated the DOM. To see the current (active) DOM with all the manipulations you'll need to use the developer tools. You can access these in most browsers from the `Tools` menu or by pressing `<F12>`. The easiest way to solve this would be to see if the company produces a public facing API that you could call in to to fetch product details.

Comment: I think that is correct.  What I am trying to do is to first render the external web page and then extract data from it.  Seems like [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org) can perform this task, but would require installing the binary.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this (e.g., in the case of JQuery, where there's no need to install any external binaries)?